# How to issue commands on remote hosts in parallel using Fabric without using a fabfile?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fabric

I have a Python script that uses Fabric to launch tests on remote hosts, get the otuput file of the tests, and do some parsing.  The Python script is not a fabfile.

I would like to launch and run the tests in parallel.  I've read about using the "@parallel" decorator but all the examples I've read has the script as a fabfile.

My code is something like this:

```
from fabric.api import *

# Copy the testfile on each of the hosts.  This is sequential, it could be
# done in parallel but doing it in parallel is not that important
def copy_test(host_list, testfile_name):
    for x in host_list:
        env['host_string'] = x

        target_testfile_name = "/tmp/" + testfile_name

        put(testfile_name, target_testfile_name)


@parallel  # Would this decorator work?
def run_test(host_list, testfile_name):

    target_testfile_name = "/tmp/" + testfile_name
    for x in host_list:
        env['host_string'] = x
        run(target_testfile_name)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    HOSTS = ['10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.11', '10.10.10.12', '10.10.10.13']

    testfile_name = "foo.py"

    copy_test(HOSTS, testfile_name)

    # I would like to launch run_test() in parallel
    run_test(HOSTS, testfile_name)
```

This is a simplified version of the code.  I have not included everything but I pass around configuration information of the hosts so that limits me in using this script as a fabfile where I issue something like:

> "fab -H '10.10.10.10' copy_test"
>
> "fab -H '10.10.10.10' run_test" -P

I could execute run_test() using the threading.Threads library but I would rather do that as a last resort.

As you can see, I am not running this as a fabfile.

Is there a way I could execute run_test() using Fabric's parallel execution model without executing my script as a "fabfile"?

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so i'll put an answer change your main to :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    HOSTS = ['10.10.10.10', '10.10.10.11', '10.10.10.12', '10.10.10.13']

    testfile_name = "foo.py"

    execute(copy_test,HOSTS, testfile_name)

    # I would like to launch run_test() in parallel
    execute(run_test,HOSTS, testfile_name)
```

if you call the fonction with `execute()`  and your fonction has the `@parallel` it'll be launched in parallel

Comment: Just an other thing, you know about the fabric's environment variable ? Because you could store your host list in `env.hosts` and then you wouldn't have to pass them as arguments

Comment: pwnsauce, thanks for the suggestion.  I will try it and see if it resolves my problem.