# How can I get this to run in parallel using Fabric?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, fabric

I asked a related question earlier:

[How to issue commands on remote hosts in parallel using Fabric without using a fabfile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38278266/how-to-issue-commands-on-remote-hosts-in-parallel-using-fabric-without-using-a-f)

I'm having problems executing tests in parallel on various test hosts.

My code looks like this:

```
@parallel  
def run_test(arg_list):
    # arg_list is a list of dictionary.  Each entry in
    # arg_list has a 'ip_address' and a 'test_config_file'

    for x in arg_list:
        ip_address = x['ip_address']
        test_config_file = x['test_config_file']
        env['host_string'] = ip_address
        # The test program "test_localhost.py" is already on all the Test hosts
        cmd = "/root/test_localhost.py --ip_addr=" + ip_address + " --config=" + test_config_file
        run(cmd)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    env.parallel = True

    # Each test host will have unique test_config_files
    arg_list = list()
    arg_list.append({'ip_address':'10.10.10.10', 'test_config_file': "config_01.json"})
    arg_list.append({'ip_address':'10.10.10.11', 'test_config_file': "config_02.json"})

    execute(run_test, arg_list)
```

I've run this code against 2+ test hosts.  I have a script that checks to see if the tests are running on the test hosts.  The tests are not run in parallel.

Instead, the tests are run sequentially - the "test_localhost.py" is first run on 10.10.10.10, then after it is finished, it is run on 10.10.10.11.

Is there anything else I need to do to make the tests run in parallel?

Note: I can't use fabfile because I am sending different test configuration files for each test host.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here’s what I would do.  The trick for different parameters for different hosts is to add info to the `env` context_manager to let you grab a hold of host-specific arguments for a task.  Just make sure that the host matches up to the key that you use for the dictionary and the parallel commands work fine.  Finally, tasks in fabric are usually run through the `fab` command.  I’ve never tried it using a native python script and am unsure of the ramifications or if any special handling needs to be done.  The typical format for a fabric project is to have tasks defined in a file called `fabfile.py` and those tasks can be run using `fab`.

In a file called `fabfile.py`:

```
from fabric.decorators import task, parallel
from fabric.operations import run
from fabric.context_managers import env

@task
def run_test(arg_list):
    # arg_list is a list of dictionary.  Each entry in
    # arg_list has a 'ip_address' and a 'test_config_file'
    env.hosts = [ x['ip_address'] for x in arg_list ]
    env.host_data = dict()
    for x in arg_list:
        env.host_data[x['ip_address']] = x
    execute(run_command)

@parallel
def run_command():
    context = env.host_data[env.host]
    cmd = '/root/test_localhost.py --ip_addr=%(ip_address)s --config=%(test_config_file)s' % context
    run(cmd)

@task 
def run_my_test():
    arg_list.append({'ip_address':'10.10.10.10', 'test_config_file': "config_01.json"})
    arg_list.append({'ip_address':'10.10.10.11', 'test_config_file': "config_02.json"})
    run_test(arg_list)
```

From the command line run:

```
fab run_my_test
```

Comment: 2ps, thanks for the advice but I can't use a fabfile because there are configuration files that need to be passed, then parsed by the script.

In my case, the fabfile.py needs to take runtime arguments.

Comment: fabric commands can take runtime arguments.  Just add arguments to function decorated with `@task`.

Comment: 2ps: Is env.host_data defined?  I wrote my script to be very similar to yours but Python complains at this line: 

        env.host_data[x['ip_address']] = x

I am using Python 2.7 and I imported the env module from fabric.context_manager

Comment: Ick, you are right, I forgot the line: env.host_data = {}

Comment: ps2, thanks for your help.

I'm able to use code similar to yours in my test script.  I can launch tasks in parallel on multiple test hosts using Fabric but without having to use a fabfile or invoke "fab run_my_test".

Thanks again.